# rdp session terminal server sendKeys

Tags: terminal, send, autoit

I don't know how can I send "windows + r" in order to open the small window (execute ...) to the terminal serveur.. Anybody can help me ?  I tried Send("#r") but it doesn't work

```
$host = "" ; <---- IP 
$hGUI = GUICreate("Terminal Serveur", 952, 675, -1, -1, $WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW +        $WS_CLIPSIBLINGS + $WS_CLIPCHILDREN)
$oRDP = ObjCreate("MsTscAx.MsTscAx.2")
$oRDP_Ctrl = GUICtrlCreateObj($oRDP, 64, 44, 800, 600)
GUICtrlSetResizing(-1, $GUI_DOCKALL)
GUICtrlSetStyle($oRDP_Ctrl , $WS_VISIBLE)
$oRDP.DesktopWidth = 800
$oRDP.DesktopHeight = 600
$oRDP.Fullscreen = False
$oRDP.ColorDepth = 16
$oRDP.AdvancedSettings3.SmartSizing = True
$oRDP.Server = $host
$oRDP.UserName = "" ; <--- Username
$oRDP.Domain = ""
$oRDP.AdvancedSettings2.ClearTextPassword = "" ; <--- Password
$oRDP.ConnectingText = "Connecting to " & $host
$oRDP.DisconnectedText = "Disconnected from " & $host
$oRDP.StartConnected = True
$oRDP.Connect()
$oShel = ObjCreate("shell.application")
$oShel_Ctrl = GUICtrlCreateObj($oShel, 64, 44, 800, 600)
GUICtrlSetStyle($oShel_Ctrl , $WS_VISIBLE)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $hGUI)
Send ("#r") !!!!
While 1
$nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
Switch $nMsg
    Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
        $oRDP.Disconnect()
       Exit
EndSwitch
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u try to do it with ShellExecute instead of opening the window first?

//Edit  I just saw tht u asked the question before and tht u want to run the command at the other computer

Comment: Yes I tried but it doesn't work exactly as I want. With this code it's perfect but now I want to launch an application in the window I create but I don't know how can I do..